# When I add new cylinder after right click I cant see primitive options

Tags: modeling

when I add new cylinder  after right click I cant see primitive options. For example numbers of vertices

Comment: the Operator box will disappear as soon as you do a new action, but you may be able to reload the parameters with the F9 key

Comment: Thank you! for answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try to do everything as in the screenshot or throw off your blender file or make a screenshot

Comment: Hi and welcome to BSE :) [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) will help you create clearer answers along with proper formatting of your images. Please try to explain a bit more detail as well, as short tips and comments tend to be removed as low quality.